# Got These credentials do not authorize access from nokia here api getlinkinfo

Tags: here-api

I'm performing the following call:

http://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=APP_ID&waypoint=LATITUDE%2CLONGITUDE&app_code=APP_CODE

it always worked until yesterday, when I started getting http 403 error with the following json error message:

```json
{
   "response":{
      "_type":"ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
      "type":"SystemError",
      "subtype":"SystemError",
      "details":"These credentials do not authorize access. Please contact your customer representative or submit a request here https://developer.here.com/contact-us to upgrade your account. You can also get valid credentials by registering for a free trial license on https://developer.here.com.",
      "metaInfo":{
         "timestamp":"2017-11-08T10:48:02Z",
         "mapVersion":"8.30.76.154",
         "moduleVersion":"7.2.201744-2851",
         "interfaceVersion":"2.6.34"
      }
   }
}
```

I checked my account but it's a Public Basic Plan one so there is no expiration or restriction on the api I'm calling.

Comment: I also tried to use a new 90-days trial plan but no way: I always get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Domains with `nokia.com` aren't supported anymore. You need to change the domain name to the actual one.
Try to use `https://route.api.here.com/`

Comment: I tried to change the url to: https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.json?app_id=APP_ID&waypoint=LATITUDE%2CLONGITUDE&app_code=APP_CODE but I keep getting the same error response